# clang: how to enable vector constructor of ext_vector_type

Tags: c++, clang

xcode uses clang and therefore you can use vectors like

```
typedef float float4 __attribute__((ext_vector_type(4)));
```

when i initialize a vector using

```
float4 v = (float4)(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
```

then all 4 components are 4.0. Is there a possibility to enable clang's vector constructors in xcode?

Comment: According to https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vector-literals, this should work, but it still doesn't with clang 11.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that with the C (and C++) syntax, when you do `(x, y, z, w)`, the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) makes it so all you get is `4.0f`. When assigning to a `float4`, it becomes a vector with all components set to `4.0f`.

Use brackets instead of parentheses, like this:

```
float4 v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

This will give you a vector with x=1, y=2, z=3 and w=4.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. For example you need to do the following: 
`float2 var1 = {1.0f, 2.0f};float2 var2 = {2.0f, 3.0f};float4 var3 = (float4)(var1.xy, var2.xy);`

Comment: @user1917057 are you sure about that? [It seems to work as intended](http://rextester.com/JFKXW73742).

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem @user529758 had. <br/> When do the following:  `float4 v = (float4)(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);`

Comment: Why are you using parentheses instead of curly brackets? That appears to be the main difference between your code and mine. Can you reproduce your problem with an online compiler?

Comment: Because curly brackets do not support partial initializers with shuffling. According to clang spec you can't write float4 v = {v1.xy, v2.zw}; You can do that only with parentheses. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html you can find detailed example in the  Vectors Literals section.

Comment: @binaryzebra Did you ever get this to work?  The `clang` docs say we can use parentheses, but it only ever works with curly braces and no partial initializers for me.